# Ember.js current_user - accessing global variable from controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I am baffled by a seemingly simple ember question. I am using [active_model_serializers meta data serialization](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#attributes) to serialize my rails current_user method from a rails controller, then extracting and setting that current_user meta json to a global ember variable using [this guy's temporary solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322945/accessing-meta-information-passed-in-a-json-server-response/14357404#14357404).

```
App.CustomRESTSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractMeta: function(loader, type, json) {
    var meta;
    meta = json[this.configOption(type, 'meta')];
    if (!meta) { return; }
    Ember.set('App.metaData', meta);
    this._super(loader, type, json);
  }
});
```

All good up until this point. Now I can access the current_user information from the console by typing in App.metaData.current_user and also from handlebars by calling a specific attribute, i.e.:

```
{{App.metaData.current_user.email}}
```

and that email attribute shows up in the template. The problem comes when I am trying to access that global variable from within an ember controller. It seems so ridiculously easy, but I can't seem to access current_user from within any ember controller. I have tried:

```
currentUserBinding: 'App.metaData.current_user',

currentUser: function() {
  return App.metaData.current_user;
}.property(),

Ember.get('App.metaData.current_user')
```

and a few other methods, but can't seem to access it. It's bizarre that I can access current_user so easily from within the console and handlebars with a direct path, but not from within an ember controller. I must be missing something obvious.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: In a similar scenario I've created a `User` model and set it as a property of the `ApplicationController`, so I can access via `controllerFor` in my routes or via `needs` in my controllers.

Comment: So then from your server you're serializing one user object, and setting a currentUser property on your ApplicationController that's bound to something like currentUser: App.User.find(0)?

Comment: Yeah, see the example below. I've also added a fiddle with a mocked request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In our app we do it same as @MilkyWayJoe suggested, but I think your approach is really interesting. Passing current_user thru JSON is a really elegant approach.

I've not experimented too much, but from what I can tell in your example the problem is nothing to do with the serializer. It's a problem with the computed property - you need to specify that it depends on `App.metaData.current_user`.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentUser: function() {
    return Ember.get('App.metaData.current_user')
  }.property('App.metaData.current_user')
});
```

This tells ember that it should re-calculate the currentUser property whenever `App.metaData.currentUser` changes. Otherwise it will run the fx once (before your ajax returns) and cache the response.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! Now I have both methods working. I've tried to avoid embedding javascript in the server-side template, but are there any advantages to that approach? I'm leaning towards sticking with the JSON serialization that now works with a correct computed property.

Comment: I think there are pros/cons to both. We wrote our app before ember-data had the metaData support so didn't consider that approach. One pro of embed-in-server-side is that you could embed not just current_user but also data for other models, might perform better than fetching JSON via api.

Answer (score 6):

You can define a variable to represent the user id in a script tag. This should be done in the server template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.user_id = 1;
</script>
```

Then in your app, you can define a property in the `ApplicationController` which will store the current user model, and then you can `find` with the `user_id` variable:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 12
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    fullName: function() {
        return '%@ %@'.fmt(
            this.get('firstName'),
            this.get('lastName')
        );
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
    userInfo: null,
    init: function() {
        // this will fire a GET request to users_controller 
        this.set('userInfo', App.User.find(window.user_id));
    }
});
```

Then your template, you can use the properties in `ApplicationController#userInfo`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>App</h1>
    {{userInfo.fullName}}
</script>
```

If you need to use this data from a route, you can use [`controllerFor`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/), or if you need to access from another controller, you can use [`needs`](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/MHUAY/))

Just keep in mind this might not be the best solution for all scenarios as it adds one more request to your app initialization, but it does the trick for me right now.

Comment: In the future I'd like to figure out a way to pass current_user through json and not embed it in the server-side template, but this works for now! Thanks man!