# Ember: a place for common property?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I' writing a hybrid app with a bit of server processing and main UI part implemented with Ember.

All auth-related functionality is server-based, so when the page loads I already know (based on cookies) if the user is authenticated or not.

In short - on the client-side I have a `userId` cookie, if it's set then the user is authenticated.

Now I need to make this data available to all templates.

I solved it for the application template (all code in CoffeeScript, but nothing special about the language there):

route

```
ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller) ->
    userId = jQuery.cookie 'userId'
    if userId == 'undefined'
      userId = null
    else
      userId = parseInt userId, 10
    controller.set 'userId', userId
```

controller

```
ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  userId: null
```

finally, the template

```
<strong>
  {{#if userId}}
    userId: {{userId}}
  {{else}}
    No user
  {{/if}}
</strong>
```

This works from the application template, but if I move it to, say, `index` template, it always says 'no user' (I expected some prototypal chain traversing for controllers).

I tried moving it to boud helper - doesn't work as well, the helper is not being called at all:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper 'userId', ->
  userId = jQuery.cookie 'userId'
  if userId == 'undefined'
    userId = null
  else
    userId = parseInt userId, 10
  userId
```

Comment: You might wanna look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070390/ember-js-current-user-accessing-global-variable-from-controller) which is somewhat similar

Comment: kind of similar yet not exactly. but it looks like I can solve it by attaching the data to the global App object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `App.deferReadiness()` and `App.advanceReadiness()` combined with setting the global properties directly on the `App` to handle that situation.  `deferReadiness()` keeps ember from initializing and `advanceReadiness()` lets ember finish initializing.

From the [ember api for `deferReadiness()`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_deferReadiness):

> Use this to defer readiness until some condition is true.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>    App = Ember.Application.create();
>    App.deferReadiness();
>
>    jQuery.getJSON("/auth-token", function(token) {
>      App.token = token;
>      App.advanceReadiness();
>    });
> ```
>
> This allows you to perform asynchronous setup logic and defer booting
>   your application until the setup has finished.

For example, you can use this to grab the user's id from the cookie before initializing ember, and store it in `App.currentUser`:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.deferReadiness();

var userId = "1234";//jQuery.cookie 'userId'
if (userId == 'undefined') {
  userId = null;
  App.set('currentUserLoggedIn', false);
  //window.location = "/login"; // redirect to login page
} else {
  userId = parseInt(userId, 10);
  App.set('currentUserLoggedIn', true);
  App.set('currentUser', userId);
  App.advanceReadiness();
}
```

You can then access this anywhere in your app using:

```
App.get('currentUser');
```

or in templates:

```
{{App.currentUser}}
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/iguyes/3/edit)

Comment: actually I ended up just attaching the data to App directly: App.userId = userId, so no need for defer/advance

still good to know about these methods

Comment: The nice thing about using defer/advance is you can wait for ajax or other async things to finish before finishing the app init. I use it specifically for querying an api endpoint to get the currently logged in user's user object and manually loading it into the store before initializing the app.