# ember.js can't get pagination from metadata

Tags: ember.js, pagination, metadata

I do an example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322945/accessing-meta-information-passed-in-a-json-server-response/14357404#14357404),but still can't get pagination

this is my store.js.coffee

```
Eme.serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.create()

Eme.serializer.configure
  meta: 'meta'
  pagination: 'pagination'

Eme.CustomAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  serializer: Eme.serializer
  namespace: "api/v1"

Eme.Store = DS.Store.extend
  revision: 13
  adapter: 'Eme.CustomAdapter'
```

this is my controller

```
Eme.PluginsController = Em.ArrayController.extend
  content: []
  pagination: (-> 
    if this.get('model.isLoaded')
      console.log @get('model.type')
      console.log @get('store').typeMapFor(modelType).metadata

      modelType = @get('model.type')
      @get('store').typeMapFor(modelType).metadata.pagination
  ).property('model.isLoaded')
```

this is response

```
{
  "meta":{
    "pagination":{
      "total_count":16,
      "total_pages":2,
      "current_page":1
    }
  },
  "plugins":[{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"zhangsan",
  }]
}
```

this is my log:

> Eme.Plugin
>
> Object {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you pasted, the `modelType` variable is output to console before it has been defined. That could be why you are not seeing the pagination data as expected.

I've created a jsbin with a slightly modified version of your code and it appears to output pagination data correctly. See: http://jsbin.com/anIKAfO/2/edit

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return App.Plugin.find();
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  pagination: function() {
    if (this.get('model.isLoaded')) {
      var store = this.get('store');
      modelType = this.get('model.type');
      console.log('modeltype: ', this.get('model.type'));
      var metadata = store.typeMapFor(modelType).metadata;
      console.log('metadata: ', metadata);
      return metadata.pagination;
    }
  }.property('model.isLoaded')
}); 

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'App.Adapter'
});

App.Plugin = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});

App.serializer = DS.RESTSerializer.create();

App.serializer.configure({
  meta: 'meta',
  pagination: 'pagination'
});

App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: App.serializer,
  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    console.log('App.Adapter.ajax:', url, type, hash);
    json = App.RESTDATA[url];
    if (json) {
      console.log('App.Adapter.ajax: Found RESTDATA: ', json);
      return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('App.Adapter.ajax: No RESTDATA for url, calling API', url);
      return this._super(url, type, hash);
    }
  }
});

App.RESTDATA = {
'/plugins':
  {
    "meta":{
    "pagination":{
      "total_count":16,
      "total_pages":2,
      "current_page":1
    }
    },
    "plugins":[{
    "id":"1",
    "name":"zhangsan"
    }]
  }
};
```